# How to Filter arrays in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I have some arrays, I need to filter this,how can i accomplish this?

The Array's are as follows

```
array (
  'Position' => 'Too Small',
  'Flavour' => 'Need Improvement',
  'Presentation' => 'Need Improvement',
  'Value_for_Money' => 'Average',
  'Choice' => 'Average',
  'Freshness' => 'Need Improvement',
  'name' => 'raj',
  'email' => 'rajasekarang.cud@gmail.com',
  'date' => '5',
  'month' => 'May',
  'year' => '2003',
  'Gender' => 'Male',
)
```

I need some specific array only, like this :

```
array (
  'name' => 'raj',
  'email' => 'rajasekarang.cud@gmail.com',
  'date' => '5',
  'month' => 'May',
  'year' => '2003',
  'Gender' => 'Male',
)
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 2):

Do it simply using [array_slice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php),

```
$fullArr=array (
  'Position' => 'Too Small',
  'Flavour' => 'Need Improvement',
  'Presentation' => 'Need Improvement',
  'Value_for_Money' => 'Average',
  'Choice' => 'Average',
  'Freshness' => 'Need Improvement',
  'name' => 'raj',
  'email' => 'rajasekarang.cud@gmail.com',
  'date' => '5',
  'month' => 'May',
  'year' => '2003',
  'Gender' => 'Male',
) ;

$output = array_slice($fullArr, 6);
print '<pre>';
print_r($output);
print '<pre>';
```

See Demo http://codepad.viper-7.com/TggDl5

**OR**

Do it using [array_flip](http://php.net/array_flip) and [array_intersect_key](http://php.net/array_intersect_key)

```
$fullArr=array (
  'Position' => 'Too Small',
  'Flavour' => 'Need Improvement',
  'Presentation' => 'Need Improvement',
  'Value_for_Money' => 'Average',
  'Choice' => 'Average',
  'Freshness' => 'Need Improvement',
  'name' => 'raj',
  'email' => 'rajasekarang.cud@gmail.com',
  'date' => '5',
  'month' => 'May',
  'year' => '2003',
  'Gender' => 'Male',
) ;
$allowed= array('name', 'email', 'date', 'month', 'year', 'Gender');

print '<pre>';
print_r(array_intersect_key($fullArr, array_flip($allowed)));
print '</pre>';
```

See Demo :http://codepad.viper-7.com/P1CuYt

Answer (score 2):

Try this code.

```
<?php
$orig_array = array(
'Position' => 'Too Small',
'Flavour' => 'Need Improvement',
'Presentation' => 'Need Improvement',
'Value_for_Money' => 'Average',
'Choice' => 'Average',
'Freshness' => 'Need Improvement',
'name' => 'raj',
'email' => 'rajasekarang.cud@gmail.com',
'date' => '5',
'month' => 'May',
'year' => '2003',
'Gender' => 'Male',
);
$needed_keys = array('name', 'email', 'date', 'month', 'year', 'Gender');
$result_array = array();
if (is_array($orig_array) && count($orig_array) > 0) {
foreach ($needed_keys as $key) {
    if (array_key_exists($key, $orig_array)) {
    $result_array[$key] = $orig_array[$key];
    }
}
}
unset($orig_array);

print_r($result_array);
```

Comment: add `if (iseet ($orig_array[$key]))`

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

```
/ The following lines will remove values from the first two indexes.
unset($array[0]);
unset($array[1]);
```

or  [array_slice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php)

```
$output = array_slice($input_array, 6);
```

or [array_diff_key](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-key.php)

```
$remove_keys = array('Position','Flavour','Presentation','Value_for_Money','Choice','Freshness');
$output = array_diff_key($input_array,array_flip($remove_keys));
```